# fillStyle not a function

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm getting an unusual error:

> ctx_wrap.fillStyle is not a function

on this line:

```
ctx_wrap.fillStyle('#b8b8b8');
```

in here:

```
...
this.paint = function() {
    self.path(ctx_wrap);
    if (!isOver) {
        ctx_wrap.fillStyle('#b8b8b8');
    } else {
        ctx_wrap.fillStyle('#d6d6d6'); 
    }
    ctx_wrap.fill()
    ctx_wrap.stroke();
};
...
```

What is strange is that, if I comment out that line, the line beneath works. These two lines are nearly identical, but the first one produces the error and the second one works:

```
ctx_wrap.fillStyle('#b8b8b8');
ctx_wrap.fillStyle('#d6d6d6');
```

Why would the first line produce the error?

Comment: How do you get the ctx_wrap object ? By using HTMLCanvasElement.getContext("2d") or special method to draw ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `ctx_wrap.fillStyle = "#COLOR"`.

The second one does not work, the console just stops at the first one and spits out the error, because it freaked out from the line of code.

Comment: thanks!  This works for the first one: ctx_wrap.fillStyle = "#b8b8b8";  But actually, this does still work for the second one: ctx_wrap.fillStyle('#d6d6d6'); - no errors, and the canvas graphics draw.  So while your solution works, I;m still not sure why one works and the other does not (???) Anyway, glad that it works.  thanks!

Comment: I'm so glad it worked for you, very strange that the second one does not work. I would really appreciate checking this answer as correct, it helps me and also tells everyone that the situation is resolved :)